# How to assert that a function does not raise an exception

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, qunit

QUnit has an assertion for testing that a function raises an exception ([QUnit/raises](http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit/raises#blockexpectedmessage)). Is it possible -- using QUnit -- to assert that a function *does not raise* an exception.

I realize that it is possible to test it like in the following code:

```
try {
    theTest();
    ok(true);
} catch (e) {
    ok(false, "Expected to succeed");
}
```

But I think it ought to be possible using QUnit. Any clues?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10190392/asserting-that-a-function-throws-exceptions-with-qunit it can help

Answer (score 18):

There is no such method in qunit

However, if you just write the following code which is much shorter, you will obtain the same result with additionnal benefits

```
theTest();
ok(true, "My function does not crash");
```

1/ If the code of a test raises an exception, qunit will mark the test as failed.

2/ If you check the "no try/catch" checkbox, you will be able to debug where the exception was thrown, which is not the case with your try/catch

Comment: Of course! That's pretty simple. And apparently a bit too simple for me to figure out. Thanks for answering :)

Comment: As it turns out, this was a bit too simple.

If the function raises an exception the test fails *without* a failure message.

If the function do not raise an exception the test succeeds as expected.

The message in the ok()-assertion is never used.

Comment: Note that you should probably also add a call to expect() inside your test() function so that the number of assertions can also be verified that way.

Comment: the ok() assertion is required, as a test without assertions will fail in qunit

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue as you mentioned in the comment whereby my test which tests no `Error` is thrown would stop "badly" showing a badly formatted `Died on test #1` message without any useful information.

I ended up using a mix of both; `raises()` for one test and `try/catch` for the other.

I used raises() for the test which tests that an `Error` is thrown, similar to this:

```
test("When myFunction() is called with a invalid instance Then Error is thrown", function () {
    // Arrange
    var testInstance = {};

    // Act
    raises(function() {
        myFunction(testInstance);
    }, Error, "myFunction() should throw an Error");

    // Assert
    // raises() does assertion
});
```

If the above throws an `Error` all is fine and if not a nice formatted message is displayed, similar to this:

```
myFunction() should throw Error
Result: No exception was thrown.
```

I then used `try/catch` for the tests which have to ensure no `Error` is thrown, similar to this:

```
test("When myFunction() is called with a valid instance Then no Error is thrown", function () {
    // Arrange
    var testInstance = new myObject();
    var result;

    // Act
    try {
        myFunction(testInstance);
        result = true;
    } catch(error) {
        result = false;
    }

    // Assert
    ok(result, "myFunction() should not throw an Error"); 
});
```

If the above throws no `Error` all is fine and if an `Error` is thrown a nice formatted message is displayed, similar to this:

```
myFunction() should not throw an Error
Source: ...
```

Comment: The above is based on the assumption that you are testing managed custom thrown errors and your `myFunction()` does do an intentional `throw new Error(...)` given a certain invalid condition. You should not test for unexpected errors off course.