# Asserting that a function throws exceptions with Qunit

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, qunit

I am new to Qunit and unit testing.

I am trying to figure out what and how to test the following function.  It does not do much at the moment but I wanted to assert that if I pass it incorrect values that errors are being thrown:

```
function attrToggle (panel, attr) {
    'use strict';

    if (!panel) { throw new Error('Panel is not defined'); }
    if (!attr) { throw new Error('Attr is not defined'); }
    if (typeof panel !== 'string') { throw new Error('Panel is not a string'); }
    if (typeof attr !== 'string') { throw new Error('Attr is not a string'); }
    if (arguments.length !== 2) { throw new Error('There should be only two arguments passed to this function')}

};
```

How do I go about asserting that an error will be thrown if any of these conditions are not met?

I tried to look at Qunit's 'raises' assertion but think I am misunderstanding it.  My interpretation would be that the test passes if an error is thrown.

So if I tested something like this:

```
test("a test", function () {
    raises(function () {
        throw attrToggle([], []);
    }, attrToggle, "must throw error to pass");
});
```

The test should pass because errors are thrown.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A couple of things wrong, a working example is at http://jsfiddle.net/Z8QxA/1/

The main issue is that you are passing the wrong thing as the second argument to `raises()`. The [second argument](http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit/raises) is used to verify that the correct Error has been thrown, so it either expects a regex, a constructor of the type of error, or a callback that allows you do your own verification.

So in your example, you were passing `attrToggle` as the type of error that would be thrown. Your code actually throws an `Error` type and so the check actually failed. Passing `Error` as the second argument works as you want:

```
test("a test", function () {
    raises(function () {
        attrToggle([], []);
    }, Error, "Must throw error to pass.");
});
```

Secondly, you don't need the `throw` keyword when calling `attrToggle()` inside `raises()`.

Answer (score 1):

yup, you pretty much got it right. [`raises()`](http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit/raises) expects a thrown error when you test a code.

Usually I use `try-catch` for my functions to catch incorrect argument types. I use `raises()` to test the `throw`. If I placed an incorrect value as an argument, and the test did not comply to `raises()` then something was not caught.